# Negative weights in a moving average?

Tags: smoothing, mean, weighted-mean

A number of well known moving averages, such as [Spencer's 15 point MA](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spencers15-PointMovingAverage.html), and [Henderson moving averages](http://www.seasonaladjustment.com/henderson.php) have *negative* weights in the averages.

What does this mean in a conceptual sense? What information are you trying to obtain from the data corresponding to those terms? Why is this more sensible than just weighting those terms = 0, and reducing some of the weights on the more central terms proportionally?

**Clarification**: As Emre correctly points out, these negative weights satisfy a mathematical criterion. But that begs the question: *what is the real world statistical/conceptual effect of that mathematical requirement*? Does it make logical sense to negatively weight data that you know isn't giving "negative" information (ie. data that isn't lying)?

Comment: If you interpret "negative" not as "lying" but as *extrapolating* you may find some insight.  (Remember that weighted averages are linear functions, so draw a picture in the Cartesian plane of the process of linearly interpolating between two points.  Positive weights correspond to the line segment between those points; negative weights reproduce the rest of the line itself.)

Comment: @whuber: sorry, but I think your point has completely eluded me. I don't really get what you mean by "draw a picture ... *of the process* ..."?

Comment: Consider two points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.  The *arithmetical process* of forming a weighted average with numerical weights $\omega_x$ and $\omega_y$ (which sum to $1$) is to compute $\omega_x\mathbf{x}+\omega_y\mathbf{y}$.  This can be algebraically rewritten as $\mathbf{x}+\omega_y(\mathbf{y-x})$.  Geometrically, this means (as a *process*) that you start at $\mathbf{x}$ and move in the direction $\mathbf{y-x}$ from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{y}$ by a multiple $\omega_y$.  When $\omega_x\lt 0$, $\omega_y\gt 1$, thereby extrapolating beyond $\mathbf{y}$.

Comment: ok, gotcha. That more or less covers emre's answer, no? But I guess I'm thinking that with linear interpolation you're on a lot safer ground than with linear extrapolation, so in a similar vein, why not just use the inner 9 points of Spencer's MA (appropriately  re-weighted)?

Comment: It's not an answer, but it's not related to Emre's answer, either.  I was only trying to point the way towards an answer to your last question ("does it make logical sense") and to suggest there may be a better way to think of this issue than in terms of "lying" or not.

Comment: When "signal" corresponds to low frequencies and "noise" to high frequencies, a [low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) enhances signal and filters out noise. Surprisingly, many low-pass filters have negative lobes. Why, intuitively ? Ask anew, perhaps over on http://dsp.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary

The weights are selected to achieve a mathematical end. In Spencer's case, the goal is to allow cubic trends to pass through the filter undistorted. This means that if we decompose the input $X_t$ into a deterministic polynomial trend component $m(t) \equiv c_3 t^3 + c_2 t^2 + c_1 t + c_0$ and a centered stochastic component $Y_t$, such that $X_t \equiv m(t) + Y_t$, then $\mathcal F \left[ X_t \right] \to m_t$ as $\sigma_Y \to 0$, where $\mathcal F$ is the filtering operation.

### Example

Here is an illustrated example using Mathematica. I'm going to compare Spencer's filter with a 15-tap double-sided symmetric moving average.

```
n = 101; c = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 4]; x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .1], n];   
result = GraphicsGrid@{{ ListPlot@MovingAverage[x + Table[c.{1, t, t^2, t^3}, 
{t, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}], {-3, -6, -5, 3, 21, 46, 67, 74, 67, 46, 21, 3, -5, -6, -3}/230], 
ListPlot@MovingAverage[ x + Table[c.{1, t, t^2, t^3}, {t, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}], 15]}, 
{ListPlot@Table[c.{1, t, t^2, t^3}, {t, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}], 
ListPlot@{x + Table[c.{1, t, t^2, t^3}, {t, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}]}}}
```

[image: Example with c={-0.26988, -0.34137, 0.670082, 0.820887}]

Clockwise from the top left: the output of Spencer's filter, the output of the symmetric filter, the noisy input ($X_t$), the cubic trend ($m_t$). This is with $c=\{-0.26988, -0.34137, 0.670082, 0.820887\}$ (the polynomial coefficients, in ascending order of degree).

#### Discussion

As you can see, Spencer's filter is more sensitive than the symmetric filter, owing to the negative weights. The low-pass effect of the symmetric filter is good for denoising (we're comparing the norm of the difference):

```
Part[#2, 8 ;; -8] - MovingAverage[#1 + #2, 15] & [x, 
Table[c.{1, t, t^2, t^3} , {t, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}]] // Norm

> 0.197244
```

for the symmetric filter versus

```
Part[#2, 8 ;; -8] - MovingAverage[#1 + #2, 
{-3, -6, -5, 3, 21, 46, 67, 74, 67, 46, 21, 3, -5, -6, -3}/230] & 
[x, Table[c.{1, t, t^2, t^3} , {t, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}]] // Norm

> 0.411789
```

for Spencer's. However, it also distorts the trend (the same test without the noise):

```
Part[#2, 8 ;; -8] - MovingAverage[#2, 15] & [x, 
Table[c.{1, t, t^2, t^3} , {t, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}]] // Norm

> 0.097972
```

versus

```
Part[#2, 8 ;; -8] - MovingAverage[#2, 
{-3, -6, -5, 3, 21, 46, 67, 74, 67, 46, 21, 3, -5, -6, -3}/230] & 
[x, Table[c.{1, t, t^2, t^3} , {t, -1, 1, 2/(n - 1)}]] // Norm

> 4.05378*10^-16
```

### Further reading

[These lecture notes](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~coad/MTH6139/tsnoteschap2.pdf) go into the derivation. You might also find resident user Rob Hyndman's article on [moving averages](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.155.4196) useful.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I kind of understood that. I should have been clearer in the question. What I kind of mean is what is the real world statistical/conceptual effect of that mathematical requirement? Does it make logical sense to negatively weight data that you know isn't giving "negative" information (ie. data that isn't lying)? +1 though, answer is still useful :) clarified the question.

Comment: This might be the best possible answer, but it'd be really good to get an example (preferably visual) of that distortion. It's difficult to conceptualise..

Comment: @Emre, sorry, shouldn't we divide by 320 instead of 230? And anyway, I think, there is no need to divide the coefficients - MovingAverage takes care of them summing to 1 (and they would not have done so if divided by 230).