# Proofs concerning a weight defined as $\frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$

Tags: self-study

I believe I understand how to do this problem. However, I do not understand it's significance. If anyone could explain the significance of these results to me I would appreciate it. Also if there is anything wrong with my proofs please correct me. Thank you!

---

### The problem is:

Consider the weights defined in 
$$
w_i
=\frac{\dot{x}_i}{\sum(\dot{x}_i^2)} 
=\frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
$$
as the deviation of the i-th value of the explanatory variable from the mean value, divided by the sum of squares of such deviations. Prove that

**a)**  $$\sum{w_i} = 0 $$
 **b)**  $$\sum{w_i^2}=\frac{1}{\sum{\dot{x}_i^2}}$$
 **c)**  $$\sum{w_i x_i}={\sum{{w_i \dot{x_i}}}} = 1$$

---

### My solution so far is:

**a)** Since we are given, $\sum{w_i} = 0 $. I assume that means we must show,

$\sum{w_i}$
$=\sum{\frac{x_i - \bar{x}}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}$
$={\frac{\sum{x_i - \bar{x}}}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}$
$={\frac{0}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}$
$[\because$ $\sum{x_i - \bar{x}}= 0]$
$=0$

**b)**

To show, $\sum{w_i^2}=\frac{1}{\sum{\dot{x}_i^2}}$

We take 
${\frac{\sum{x_i - \bar{x}}}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}*
 {\frac{\sum{x_i - \bar{x}}}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}$
$={\frac{\sum{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2*\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2}}$
$= \frac{1}{\sum{\dot{x}_i^2}}$

**c)**
For C I see that for $x_i = \dot{x}_i$ then $x_i = x_i - \bar{x}$ and thus that $\bar{x} = 0$ for $\sum{w_i x_i}={\sum{{w_i \dot{x_i}}}} = 1$ to hold.

IFF $\bar{x} = 0$ then this derivation will be very straight forward.

However, can this be shown more generally?

Comment: Have you had a regression course yet? If so, these equations help establish the variance of the OLS estimators. It's also a nice exercise proving these facts.

Comment: I have had an introductory statistics course and these questions are from the first homework of my elementary econometrics course which by definition will basically all be about regression analysis. I just didn't understand what makes these facts useful.

Comment: Hints: write $w_i = \frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{\sum_m (x_m-\bar{x})^2}$ which emphasizes that the denominator is a _constant_ that does not depend on $i$ at all, that is, $w_i = \frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{c}$. Can you show that  $\sum_i c\cdot w_i = \sum_i(x_i-\bar{x})$ equals $0$ and thus prove A)? Similarly for B) (your proof is incorrect, by the way -- that product (denoted by $*$) does not equal what you say it does). For C), use $cw_ix_i = cx_i^2 - c\bar{x}x_i$.

Comment: That will give you some *negative* weights, some other posts with negative weights: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27213/negative-weights-in-a-moving-average, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139131/negative-weights-in-maximum-likelihood-method, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369611/can-an-optimal-weighted-average-ever-have-negative-weights